# How to preserve types while converting Scala Spark DF -> RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to convert a dataframe to an RDD. My DataFrame has typed columns, like so:

```
df.printSchema
root
 |-- _c0: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- num_hits: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- session_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)
```

When I go to convert this to an rdd using `df.rdd`, I get an rdd that is of the type `Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]` but when I access each entry using `rdd(0)(0)`, `rdd(0)(1)`, etc. I get that they all have the type `Any`. How do I keep the same typing that the DataFrame has when I convert it to an RDD? Put another way: how do I get the columns in my rdd to have types `Int`, `Int`, `String`, `String`, so that they match the Dataframe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just convert your `DataFrame` to `Dataset[(Int, Int, String, String)]`, such as

```
scala> val df = Seq((1, 2, "a", "b")).toDF("_c0", "num_hits", "session_name", "user_id")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_c0: int, num_hits: int ... 2 more fields]

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- _c0: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- num_hits: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- session_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)


scala> val rdd = df.as[(Int, Int, String, String)].rdd
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int, String, String)] = MapPartitionsRDD[3] at rdd at <console>:25
```

If `_c0` and `num_hits` can be `null`, just change `Int` to `java.lang.Integer`.

Comment: That did it. Thanks! Is there a reason why df.rdd doesn't pick up the types?

Comment: Because DataFrame doesn't know what's the type you want. `as[(Int, Int, String, String)]` basically just tells Spark that you want to convert Row to `(Int, Int, String, String)`